# Magento 2 - Add column to a table by using the declarative schema

Tags: magento2, database, declarative-schema

I try to add two columns to the **sales_order_grid** table by following the *[declarative schema](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html)*.

## Attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order_grid" resource="default">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="customer_note" length="1024" nullable="true" comment="Customer Note"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="allocated_sources" length="256" nullable="true" comment="Allocated Sources"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

But if I call `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then the columns are not getting added.

So I changed the version in `MODULE/etc/module.xml` from *1.0.0* to *1.0.1* and tried it again, but it still does not work.

In the documentation it says:

> When adding a new column into table, remember to generate the
> db_schema_whitelist.json file.

So I generated the whitelist with `php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Company_Sales`

**MODULE/etc/db_schema_whitelist.json**

```
{
    "sales_order_grid": {
        "column": {
            "customer_note": true,
            "allocated_sources": true
        }
    }
}
```

... and tried `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` again. But it still fails.

I even deleted the entry `Company_Sales` from the table `setup_module` but it makes no difference too.

What am I missing?

---

Magento Version: 2.4.2

Comment: try to add engine="innodb" in <table name="sales_order" resource="default" engine="innodb"> and also use php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist command before php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I tried it, but it does still not work.

Comment: I just found this:

"When adding a new column into table, remember to generate the db_schema_whitelist.json file."
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html#add-a-column-to-table

Comment: did you generated whitelist for your module/

Comment: if not then first generate for it and after upgrade delcarative schema file.

php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=YourModule_Name

or for all

php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist

Comment: @S.P, yes I tried it. The **db_schema_whitelist.json** does exist, have a look at my updated question please.

Comment: what is sequence of your module.

it should be like

 <sequence>
<module name="Magento_Sales"/>
</sequence>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It actually worked all the time !!!

The problem was my SQL Viewer Software HeidiSQL (v12.0.0.6468) which has a bug and is not showing new data even after refreshing, you need to close the software and open it again to make it work or respectively close the connection and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your extension order, It should be after `Magento_Sales`.

**etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="{{Vendorname}}_{{Modulename}}">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**etc/db_schema.xml**.

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order_grid">
        <column name="customer_note" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar" comment="Customer Note" length="1024"/>
        <column name="allocated_sources" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar" comment="Allocated Sources" length="1024"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/355916/66769